# Accessing $location from injector

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple angularjs application with a single router at the moment :

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
            .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/editFilter/:id', {templateUrl: '/webapp/template/filterDetail'});
            }])
```

My goal is to call the editFilter template when I need it.
I am trying to retrieve the $location like that :

```
angular.injector(['myApp']).get('$location')
```

but it fails with

> Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.1/$injector/unpr?p0=%24rootElementProvider%20%3C-%20%24rootElement%20%3C-%20%24location%20%3C-%20%24route

If I call `angular.injector(['myApp']).get('$location')` it returns true.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? I have try several workaround but everytime I end up with a very similar error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would have read the [error page](http://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector%3aunpr?p0=%24rootElementProvider%20%3C-%20%24rootElement%20%3C-%20%24location%20%3C-%20%24route) you see that you forgot to include certain dependencies. Please don't forget to include them. The one failing now is $rootElement, as you can read in the error. Include this one, and try again to see if other dependencies should be included.

EDIT:
 OK, I was wrong, after some reading I noticed that this method:

```
angular.injector(['myApp']).get('$location')
```

creates a new injector instance. This is not what you want I think.
So I don't know what is your case but if you are in AngularJS just inject the $injector instance. If not in AngularJS call

```
$injector = angular.element([DOM element]).injector();
$injector.get('$location');
```

Comment: I have read the error, but can't figure out why the dependency is failing. $rootElement is part of the angular context so I don't get why the injector can't find it.  What do you mean by include them?

Comment: Seems to work! I can get a $location object. The only thing is that it seems that calling path(myPath) on it has no effect. I guess it's an other problem... Thanks for that.

Comment: My 2nd problem is fixed, just needed to call $apply on rootScope