# angularjs injector with location service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-injector

I am testing some Angular.js code with Jasmine. To do this I need an Angular injector:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngRoute', 'mainModule']);
```

This works fine, but when I get to testing a controller that uses $location, I have to add that to the injector:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngRoute', 'location', 'mainModule']);
```

Now this throws an error:

```
Error: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module location due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'location' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

How can I include $location service there? Thanks.

-------------- EDIT -----------------

due to not many answers I thought I will add some details.

Here is a controller I am trying to test (or the definition of it, I won't be pasting all code):

```
var app = angular.module('mainModule');

app.controller('appController', ['$window', '$scope', '$location', '$wsService', '$userService', '$labelService', function ($window, $scope, $location, $wsService, $userService, $labelService) {
    //body of the controller
}]);
```

You have already seen how I create the injector in my unit test in the original post, here is how I use the injector to create the controller:

```
var scope;
var controller;
var getController = function() {
    injector.invoke( ['$rootScope', '$controller', function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope      = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('appController', {$scope: scope});
    }]);
};
```

Hope this will help with producing some potential answers. Thanks

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674326/accessing-location-from-injector

Comment: while this might sound similar, the thread you have linked doesn't answer my question. I am doing unit testing, so I run the JavaScript files within the console, not browser, without creating any DOM, therefore I have no way of creating injector by passing DOM element. I need either a way of injecting location service, or somehow mocking it in my unit tests and passing it to the injector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question. Here is how to test the following controller:

```
var app = angular.module('mainModule');

app.controller('appController', ['$window', '$scope', '$location', '$userService', function ($window, $scope, $location, $userService) {
    //body of the controller
}]);
```

**1** In unit test create injector:

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngRoute', 'mainModule']);
```

**2** Invoke services required:

```
injector.invoke( ['$userService',  function ($userService) {
    service     = $userService;
}]);
```

**3** Mock location service:

```
var mockLocation = {
    path : ""
};
```

I just needed `path` for the controller I am testing, thus I did not mock anything else, but mock whatever else you need.

**4** Invoke the controller:

```
var scope;
var controller;
var getController = function() {
    injector.invoke( ['$rootScope', '$controller', function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope      = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('appController', {$scope: scope, $location: mockLocation});
    }]);
};
```

Now the controller can be used in unit tests.
This did get rid of 'unknown provider' and other errors related to location service.
[This](http://metalcoder.ghost.io/mocking-angularjs-services-in-unit-test/) blog post helped me with an answer, thanks to the author.