# How do i use $location in a normal function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-injector

I have a angular app where half is angular js and half is plane js like ajax.  So how do i use $location inside that function without passing it as a function parameter.

```
function x() {
   $location.path('/error').replace();
}
```

Now i wish to know how to use `$location` inside a normal javascript function. Basically i have a function that is being called from at least 20 places. In that function i wish to do replacestate.

Comment: Consider doing the opposite and integrate the plain JS stuff to your Angular app.

Comment: could u plz elobarte

Comment: Uh, well, as I said, use your functions inside your Angular controllers... In short, don't try to "augment" a regular JS app with Angular. Build an Angular app from the start. And it would be nice if you could take some time to write "Could you please elaborate."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `angular.injector` that will provide and access to provider from outside.

```
angular.injector(['app']).get('$location')
```

For more information Refer this [**SO Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20674571/2435473)

**Update**

You could directly apply injector on element, that will give access to all the service present inside that module.

```
angular.element('body').injector().get('$location'); //body can replace by your element.
```

Comment: i dont have any modules

Comment: what is body. and i think you are missing a dot

Comment: also this is giving me error  as go function not found  angular.element('body').injector().get('$location').go("/error/404").replace();

Comment: @aWebDeveloper `$location` does have go event..do you want to do `$state.go`

Comment: still go is undefined

Comment: I tried redirect but without any use. It doesn't redirect i.e change view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80278/discussion-between-awebdeveloper-and-pankajparkar).

Comment: @aWebDeveloper sorry I can't come on chat here try this `angular.element('body').injector().get('$location').path('/error/404').replace()` are you using ui-router

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend wrapping that function as a service. And change myFunction and x to a sensible name. Change app to whatever your app name is.

```
function x($location) {
   $location.path('/error').replace();
}

x.$inject = ['$location'];

angular.module('app').function('myFunction', x);
```